# When is it safe to delete files when using file-based streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm using file-based Streaming with Spark, and I would like to delete old files from disk.

My Spark app is very simple, just read text files, count(), and pprint(). It works fine. No windowing or anything.

But, with a batch interval of say, 5 seconds, if I delete files after say, 5 minutes Spark will complain of a missing file.

Is it related to garbage collection? Do the source files need to exist for the lifetime of the RDD in the DStream? Can I force my DStream to discard RDD, after a certain interval.

I should mention I'm not using HDFS, just the filesystem (have mounted NFS).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting files can create problems in two ways:-

Firstly, the `DStream.clearMetadata(..)` (and methods on derived classes) are responsible for removing old RDDs.

`DStream` considers the `rememberDuration` - which is computed on the batch interval, the `minRememberDuration`, etc.

It seems sensible to only delete files for which the associated RDD not longer exists.

Secondly, during the process of finding new files the `FileInputDStream` will first obtain a directory listing, and then query each file for its last modified time in turn (in `findNewFiles(..)`), to decide whether the file is new. Consequently, if a file is deleted between these two steps, even if is old - the second check will fail - as the file no longer exists.

Deleting old files can work for a while - but it will fail sooner or later. If the time taken to list new files approaches the batch interval, failure becomes increasingly likely.

As a workaround, one could specify a custom file filter and use this to reject files based on timestamp - but handle the case that the file was missing. (The custom filter is checked before the second check on the file modified time).